# Flexbox flex-wrap: is there a way to force wrap over growth?

Tags: multiline, flexbox, word-wrap

I have a set of flex-items vertically stacked. The flex container is set to wrap. I would like it to wrap as soon as possible so it will fill the page horizontally instead of growing vertically. Plus the items are filled with dynamic text so I don't want to set a fixed height nor see them cropping.

**HTML**

```
<div class="fc v menu">
  <div class="fa">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
      <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
      <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
    </ul>  
  </div>
  <div class="fa">ITEM 2</div>
  <div class="fa">ITEM 3</div>
  <div class="fa">ITEM 4</div>
  <div class="fa">ITEM 5</div>
  <div class="fa">ITEM 6</div>
  <div class="fa">ITEM 7</div>
  <div class="fa">ITEM 8</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fc {
  display: flex;
}

.fc.menu {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 15em;
}

.menu > div {
  padding: 1em;
}

.fa {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  width: 10em;
  height: 5em;
}

.fc.v {
  flex-direction: column;
  background: pink;
  border: 4px fuchsia solid;
}
```

You can see in the [codepen](http://codepen.io/stilllife00/full/JAbpB) that even if it is possible to force a sort of wrap the content will not fit the container anymore.

Comment: can you elaborate more? perhaps adding an image as reference

Comment: there is a link to a codepen. You will see the flex item not growing based on the content